# Iterators returned by begin/end methods

Tags: c++, loops, iterator

In the example below, class `A` has `begin/end` methods, which allows to iterate with a loop like `for (auto x : A(10)) {}`. In this example, the iteration simply iterates over a range of integers.

In order to illustrate my point, the inner `iterator` struct holds another field `cache_` that takes some memory (for instance for prefetching some items to be returned by further steps in the iteration).

Although `cache_` is likely to be used only by the iterator returned by `begin`, my concern is that the iterator returned by `end` has also this field, which is not really needed since this iterator acts like a sentinel in order to tell whether the iteration is still running or not.

My question is: **is there a smart way to avoid the extra cost of the `cache`field for the iterator returned by method `end` ?**

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdio>

class A
{
private:

    size_t N_;

    struct iterator
    {
        size_t idx_;
    
        size_t cache_[1024];
    
        iterator (size_t idx) : idx_(idx) {}
        
        bool operator != (const iterator & other) const { return idx_ != other.idx_; }

        void operator ++ ()  {  ++ idx_;  }

        size_t operator* () const  { return idx_; }
    };


public:

    iterator begin()  { return iterator( 0); }
    iterator end()    { return iterator(N_); }
    
    A (size_t N) : N_(N) {}
};


int main ()
{
    A a(10);
    printf ("begin: %d\n", sizeof(a.begin()));  // begin: 8200
    printf ("end  : %d\n", sizeof(a.end()));    // end  : 8200
}
```

Comment: Don't put the cache in the iterator. Put it somewhere else.

Comment: Adding cache to iterator goes against general idea of iterators in C++. Iterator type should be small and cheap to copy. Your `iterator` costs a lot to create and to iterate (and also doesn't meet the requirements of [forward iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ForwardIterator)). If adding cache actually helps with anything, maybe you are using wrong data structure to begin with?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen  actually, a cache is useful in my case (i.e. specific hardware architecture). An equivalent scenario would be an iteration over the lines of a file, where 'prefetching' N lines into a cache avoids too many calls to the file system.

Comment: It is unlikely that the cache needs to belong to the iterator. Consider whether the container (`A` in thie case) can be responsible for it instead.

Comment: @edrezen Okay, but that is not what iterator should do. Everything in standard library relies on the assumption that iterators are cheap to copy and takes them by value. And caching in the iterator itself isn't great either - imagine for example quite a normal use: `for(auto iter = a.begin() + 10000; iter != a.end(); ++iter)` - you would prefetch first elements to construct `begin()` and them immediately discard them to advance the iterator. It's not impossible to prevent `end()` iterator from having cache (e.g. with inheritance), but iterator is too unaware of surroundings to make good cache.

Comment: *this iterator acts like a sentinel* - Then you could make a special distinct sentinel type for it.

Answer (score 3):

Don't put the cache in the iterator. Put it somewhere else. –

1. In some cases, the data strucuture itself should have the cache.
2. In some cases, it makes sense to wrap the data structure with another caching class that has the same interface. This cleanly separates the cache from the data structure logic.
3. Maybe it doesn't make sense for the data structure to expose iterators directly. Instead, it should expose a `view` object, and the `view` object has a cache, and you can iterate over the view. This is very similar to #2, but exposes the cache to the callers.
4. Maybe the `begin()` method allocates a cache on the heap, and returns an iterator with a `shared_ptr` to the cache. This is similar to #3, but hides the cache from the callers, but is also slightly slower, as it requires heap allocation and atomic operations.

Comment: just to add.... its uncommon but not impossible that an iterator holds a reference to the container. Eg `std::back_insert_iterator`s do this.Its an implementation detail but the pointer is there (actually the member is protected)

Answer (score 2):

Don't store the cache in the iterator but in the container.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdio>

class A {
    size_t N_;
    size_t cache_[1024];        
    struct iterator {
        size_t idx_;
        A* container;            
        iterator(size_t idx, A* container) : idx_(idx),container(container) {}            
        bool operator!=(const iterator & other) const { return idx_ != other.idx_; }   
        void operator++() { ++idx_; }    
        size_t operator*() const  { return idx_; }
    };
public:    
    iterator begin()  { return iterator( 0,this); }
    iterator end()    { return iterator(N_,this); }        
    A (size_t N) : N_(N) {}
};

int main () {
    A a(10);
    printf("begin: %d\n", sizeof(a.begin()));
    printf("end  : %d\n", sizeof(a.end()));  
}
```

[Possible Output](https://godbolt.org/z/eWoKvGebj):

```
begin: 16
end  : 16
```

It is ok to use a raw pointer here. It gets invalidated when the `A` instance is destroyed. Thats what iterators do: the get invalid when the container is gone.